# How to update a row where checbox is checkbox is ticked - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to update certain rows where checkboxes are ticked. I am able to get the rows every cells content but not able to update them.

I'm trying to update 7th cell's content like this:

```
$.each($("input[name='eachSelector']:checked").parents("tr"), function () {
    $(this).find('td:eq(7)').innerText = "this is modified";
});
```

I am able to get all the cells values of the checked rows like this below values is an array.

```
$.each($("input[name='eachSelector']:checked").parents("td").siblings("td"), function () {
    values.push($(this).text());
});
```

how to update the cells values and add some css to it

Comment: Have you tried .text instead of .innerText?

Comment: yes , not working .

Comment: Can you try $(this).find('td:eq(7)').html("this is modified");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in your code. You are trying to use a DOM method on a jquery object. You should change this line

```
$(this).find('td:eq(7)').innerText = "this is modified";
```

to

```
$(this).find('td:eq(7)').text("this is modified");
```

Comment: how to add css to that same row

Comment: it worked , please tell me how to add the css to it ?

Comment: did this fix your initial issue? to add css directly, you can do `$(this).find('td:eq(7)').css("background", "red");`, or you can do `$(this).find('td:eq(7)').addClass("red-bg");` if you have a `.red-bg` class defined.